# Definition Query Current Date SQL Server Native Syntax Error 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, sql-server, definition-query

I have this definition query that worked for a layer from a file geodatabase. Now the same query will not work from the same layer in an SDE. I am getting a 'SQL Server Native Client Syntax' error. Any thoughts?

```
ExprDate <= (CURRENT_DATE + 30) AND ExprDate >= CURRENT_DATE
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try it with getdate()

```
ExprDate <= (GETDATE() + 30) AND ExprDate >= GETDATE()
```

Comment: In addition, SQL Server supports the BETWEEN operator: `ExprDate BETWEEN GetDate() AND GetDate() + 30`