# Query Builder Expression using NOW () function

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, sql, query, datetime

I have a date field named "TermDate'.  I would like an expression in Query Builder to only show features where termination date is in the future.  My date field displays as '2017-09-27 09:59:01' I'm using Enterprise Geodatabase with SQL server. I thought I could just use the NOW() function but I'm having no luck. I am using arcGIS 10.2.

I have a polygon feature class that is symbolized with shading for parcels that have a recovery agreement. After a certain period of time, the recovery agreements expire and I would like those to no longer be visible, so that only those with termination dates in the future appear on the map.

Comment: Probably duplicate : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138272/definition-query-current-date-sql-server-native-syntax-error-10-2

Answer (score 1):

getdate() is the way to get Now under query builder

Comment: Happy to helped you , don't forget to mark the answer as resolve